# NEAR protocol - dev env set up on Windows 10 - error when executing npx create-near-app@latest

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I am trying to set up the development env on Windows 10. Installed Node.js, yarn and RUST on windows. Then to set up the project, I tried "npx create-near-app@latest" and was prompted to install WSL.. which I did. I re-executed 'npx' command in ubuntu terminal that got installed with WSL but am still getting the same error:

> s_wankhede@Sharad-Asus:~$ npx create-near-app@latest
> '\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\s_wankhede'
> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
> UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
> ======================================================
>  Welcome to NEAR! Learn more: https://docs.near.org/
>  Let's get your dApp ready.
> ======================================================
> (NEAR collects anonymous information on the commands used. No personal information that could identify you is shared)

Notice: On Win32 please use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
Exiting now.

Questions:

1. Should I be installing Node.js, yarn and RUST in ubuntu (WSL on windows 10)?
2. What can I do solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

OK. Finally I could figure it out after reading lot of articles and lots of trial and error. Here are the simple steps to resolve it and of course these are for machines running Windows.

1. Install Linux on Windows with WSL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install  This MUST be the first step
2. Install Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
3. Install RUST - (I am writing contracts in RUST) - https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-01-installation.html Also add wasm toolchain: rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
4. Install Yarn : npm install -g yarn
5. Set up the project : npx create-near-app@latest

Comment: strage I did all of these, and I run Ubuntu (shell) and it still thinks I am on windows. Reboots didn't work

Comment: aahh those stuff needs to be reinstalled ON LINUX wsl -.- man man man 5hours lost.